# how do I get the last item from the listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop

My problem is about handling drag and drop in a ListView.

So I get the selected ListViewItem.

```
ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection itemCollection = (ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection");
```

If i move a new element via drag&drop (for example from windows explorer), the itemCollection equals null, because i dont select an item in the listview.

```
private void DragDropHandler(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
        ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection itemCollection = (ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection");

        if (itemCollection == null)
        {
            itemCollection = (ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.ListView");
        }
}
```

for this case I would get the last element in list view, how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var r = Enumerable.Empty<ListViewItem>();

if(this.listView1.Items.Count > 0)
    r = this.listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>();

var last = r.LastOrDefault();

if (last != null)
{
    // do your stuff
}
```