# get last checked item from listview c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

i have list view control with image binding. i want to get last checked item index on button click.for example user select 5 images from the 10 images.
Let say from 3rd index to 6th index
how to check user select which of the last index image on button click.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what your question is.
But if all you want is to get the last item of the selection.

Here is the link to the msdn site: [ListView.SelectedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx)

This should work for you (Where ListView1 is the name of your listview):

```
ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection items = 
        ListView1.SelectedItems;

var lastItem = items[items.Count-1];
```

Here is the code with LINQ: (Coming from this thread: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945877/3799142)

```
var r = Enumerable.Empty<ListViewItem>();

            if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
                r = listView1.SelectedItems.OfType<ListViewItem>();

            var last = r.Last();
```

Comment: @BilalSohail I have updated the answer. Please let me know if you need more help! I recommend using the second snippet of code (with LINQ)